# IBM MQ | Memory Leak | Heap Dump

Tags: java, memory-leaks, websphere, ibm-mq, heap-dump

**websphere version - 8.5.5.17**

```
unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version
// Not Output

unzip -p com.ibm.mqbind.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version
// Not Output

unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version
Implementation-Version: 7.0.1.4 - k701-104-110104
com.ibm.mq.jar - Manifest-Version: 1.0

com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar - Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.4.2 (IBM Corporation)

com.ibm.mqbind.jar -  Manifest-Version: 1.0

Java 1.8
```

We are using MQ's for sending the data. Application has been running for years with daily restart of the servers. Now we wanted to reduce the same from daily to weekly, but we have started getting heap/memory errors.

On generating heap dump and analysing we found below problems

```
Leak suspect    12,338,040 bytes (11.62 %) of Java heap is used by 106 instances of com/ibm/rmm/transmitter/QueueT
Total size  12,338,040 bytes
Size    424 bytes
Name    array of com/ibm/rmm/transmitter/Submitter
Number of children  106
Number of parents   1
Owner address   0xc1b423b8
Owner object    com/ibm/ws/dcs/vri/transportAdapter/rmmImpl/rmmGroup/RmmPtpGroup
Address 0xc645af70
First single ancestor   com/ibm/ws/dcs/vri/transportAdapter/rmmImpl/rmmGroup/RmmPtpGroup at 0xc645af70




Leak suspect    27,580,544 bytes (27.54 %) of Java heap is used by 7 instances of java/util/HashMap$Node
Contains an instance) of the leak suspect:
- array of com/ibm/rmm/transmitter/Submitter holding 11,990,072 bytes at 0xc53e9730
Total size  27,580,544 bytes
Size    64 bytes
Name    array of java/util/HashMap$Node
Number of children  7
Number of parents   1
Owner address   0xc2b6bbf0
Owner object    java/util/HashMap
Address 0xc2b6bc18
First single ancestor   sun/nio/ch/EPollSelectorImpl at 0xc2b6bc18
```

On a high level, i can see in the code we are calling below in finally block

```
MQQueue -> close()
MQQueueManager -> disconnect()
```

Not sure if some change are required in code to cleanup the resources or some library version or websphere needs to be updated.

I upgraded the said client library in comment section and i get below errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/ibm/mq/jmqi/JmqiMQ.isLocal()Z (loaded from file:/opt/middleware/availments/WebSphere/85-64/installedConnectors/wmq.jmsra.rar/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@bf93861d) called from class com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI
```

I checked with MQ support on this issue.

You cannot use an installed MQ client when running within WAS. You have to use an MQ resource adapter.
As per the following link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031610_.htm

In order for you to use MQ 9.1 MQ RA, you have to run a version of WAS that supports JMS 2.0. WAS 7, 8 ad 8.5 only support JMS 1.1. As such in order for you to be able to use MQ RA 9.1, you will need to upgrade WAS to 9.0.5.

Comment: @JoshMc added required versions

Comment: @JoshMc updated question answering yours. I only see implementation version in 1 jar, for rest nothing inside manifest file

Comment: 7.0 has been out of support for 5 days short of 5 years.  WAS 8.5 itself comes with the resource adapter from 7.1 MQ version which outside of being bundled is out of support.   I would suggest you try the single com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar from either 9.1.0.6 or 9.2.0.0.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks i will try, also is this supported with current websphere version 8.5.5.17

Comment: @JoshMc Also migrating to new version, does it involve any config changes at server or code level, just wanted to be sure about the impact of this. Also is memory issues related to older versions

Comment: Hi Ankur, I can't tell you that updating will fix the problem, but certainly you are not going to get a fix from IBM at the version you are currently using.  You could try updating to just the latest of the unsupported version (7.1.0.14), but you will still be at a unsupported version.  Most of the time IBM APIs are backward compatible, so a program that works against 7.0 should work against a future version of the product, but in some cases I have seen where programs were relying on something that was considered a defect by IBM which was fixed in a later version.  Always test in non-prod 1st.

Comment: @JoshMc Somewhere i read, 
In general IBM supports one version above or below, so

- MQ client version 8 should work with MQ server version 7, 8 or 9

- MQ server version 8 should work with MQ client version 7, 8 or 9

It means my server 8.5.5.17 should work with client 9.x (allclient jar) ?

Comment: `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` requires Java 8 which you mentioned you are using, so it should work.  Also I know that for example MQ v5.2 java clients can still connect to a MQ v9.1 queue manager.  IBM attempts to maintain this compatibility some times at the cost of leaving things in place from 20 years ago that no longer make sense today.

Comment: @JoshMc Updated my question with errors and discussion after upgrading client library

Comment: Hi Ankur, in that case I noted the page you mentioned says "The resource adapter also contains the IBM MQ classes for Java. The classes are automatically available to applications that are running in an application server that the resource adapter has been deployed into, and allow applications that are running in that application server to use the IBM MQ classes for Java API when they are accessing resources of an IBM MQ queue manager."  This means that you should be able to remove the com.ibm.mq*jar files that you currently reference from 7.0.1.1 and just let it pickup the 7.1 version.